# SHA256 value for large binaries when using Ruby

Tags: ruby, sha256

I want the SHA256 values for some large binary files. Is this possible using Ruby? `Digest::SHA2` does not seem to be usable as expects strings and not files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file on disk? - I would just use a call to shell using another utility program and avoid reading it into the Ruby runtime memory at all, e.g. using [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) + `sha256sum`

Is the file coming over IO (like the network)? - Use a [streaming read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/IO.html#method-i-read) on the IO object and [compute the SHA in chunks](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html#method-i-3C-3C)

e.g. something like this:

```rb
sha = Digest::SHA2.new
File.open(file_path) do |f|
  while chunk = f.read(256) # only load 256 bytes at a time
    sha << chunk
  end
end
sha.hexdigest # returns what you want
```